# Error on FastLane (NSF) letter of Reference System for the NSFPF

Tags: postdocs, nsf

The NSF postdoctoral application is due in less than 2 weeks and I am trying to send out invitations for my reference letters.  However, for the past week (on fastlane.gov) I have gotten the same error.

"A database error occured while performing fastlane.pdoc.ProcessReferenceLetter."

I contacted the NSF by email and by phone and haven't gotten any response by either format.  Is there anyone getting this?

Comment: Call and email the FastLane User Support line 1-800-673-6188 and fastlane@nsf.gov. They are open 7a-9p M-F and are pretty good about answering the phone during those hours.

Comment: I have actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Screen shot and date stamp every attempt to do this operation until it works. Call the helpdesk [800 number](https://www.fastlane.nsf.gov/contacts/contact_fl.jsp) back every hour during business hours until someone answers the phone, but don't just leave message after message if it goes to voicemail. If you haven't already, send invites via email personally to each of your references so that they know the request from FastLane will be coming eventually. Tell each of your references about the problem so that they'll be prepared to take alternative action if NSF gives you a workaround. Keep good records of all your attempts.

If you can figure out who the cognizant program officer is for the specific fellowship you are applying for, write them an email Monday after you have tried to get in touch with the FastLane user support folks again with a short explanation of your problem and ask them for options.

FastLane being down on broken is usually a great reason for NSF to give you an exception to a deadline.

As noted in the comments, there is some upcoming Fastlane downtime due to the [NSF financial system upgrade](http://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2014/nsf14083/nsf14083.jsp), but that shouldn't be the problem today or for the rest of the week. The FastLane user support team is usually very responsive, but with the financial system update going on, they may be swamped.

Finally, you might also try talking to the Sponsored Research Office/Office of Sponsored Projects/etc. at your current university. They work with staff at NSF all the time, and may have contacts that can help you.

Comment: This answer majorizes the answer I was going to leave. Bottom line: it sucks that you're having trouble and not getting help for it, but you shouldn't let it derail your application (or impact the lives of the letter writers), and the NSF should be willing to act to prevent that from happening: NSF program officers are very reasonable people.

Comment: I just got the letters to send out yesterday so maybe it was a bit of a fluke.  I am accepting this answer because it is great general advice.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is now a year old but I was just working on my NSF PRFB application on FastLane today (2015 and a year later), ran into the same error and stumbled on this page. I called FastLane help and they were able to resolve the problem. The person who helped me figured out that you have to re-save the "Cover Sheet" component of the application. He said the reference letter writer submission refers to this part of the application and so it needs to be updated/completed for some reason.

He did this for me but I'm assuming he just opened the "Cover Sheet" in the main "Form Preparation" window by clicking "Go", cleared something and changed it back to what it was before and saved it. You might also be able to just click the "Go" next to "*Remainder of the Cover Sheet". When I do this it says "The Remainder of the CoverSheet has been automatically filled in and saved." If you are able to re-save, the "Saved" date next to "Cover Sheet" in the "Form Preparation" window should change to the current date.

Once this was done I was able to add a reference letter writer without getting the error message. I hope this helps someone else out there if they run into the same problem!